# The java process spawned using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) is not getting terminated

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

Please check the following snippet where am I trying to spawn a process using runtime exec command and after am waiting for that process to terminate using p.waifor() method, but the java process spawned is not getting terminated even if it has finished its execution. The execution will stop at this line p.waitFor().

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( "java -jar " + path + " " );
        if( arguments != null && !arguments.isEmpty() )
        {
            for( int i = 0; i < arguments.size(); i++ )
            {
                sb.append( arguments.get( i ) + " " );
            }
        }

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( sb.toString() );

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( p.getInputStream() ) );
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while( (line = in.readLine()) != null )
        {
            stringBuilder.append( line );
        }

        int statusCode = p.waitFor();
        in.close();
```

Comment: What is the other process doing?

Comment: The other process is fetching some data from the cassandra , processes it and saves the processed output back to cassandra.

Comment: Have you checked this from command line? Are you sure it is not asking for any input? Are you sure that it terminates when ran from command line?

Comment: What happens if you run the same command from the command line? Are you 100% convinced that it will then terminate? (as: I am not; since it shouldnt make a difference if your java run is triggered from another JVM; or from a command line)

Comment: Yes I tested it in the command line its not terminating . Actually the finally block in the main method is getting executed but its not terminating.

Comment: In that case, the problem is most likely in the program that is exec-ed, not the code that does the exec-ing.  (And the exec-ed code >>isn't<< terminating.)

Comment: Wait, on the command line (so, outside of this code block you've given us) the process being invoked doesn't terminate?? Why do you think there's any problem with this code then?

Comment: Okay then what could be the issue ? why is it not getting terminated even after the finally block executes.

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.